# MYSQL compare 2 tables and set the values

Tags: python, mysql

I have an issue with my MySQL database. I am programming it in python.

I have 2 tables: `Raspberry_data` and `Operation1`.

I must read the data from Operation1 and copy some values from Operation1 to Raspberry_data table. The issue that some columns in Raspberry_data are identical which causes the query to work incorrectly.

Please check the following query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4c2ef/5

I must update `Current_operation` and `ID` columns in the `Raspberry_data` table from the data in `Operation1`.

The expected result:

```
Current_operation = 1    ID = 4

Current_operation = 1    ID = 6
```

However, the result is :

```
Current_operation = 1    ID = 4

Current_operation = 1    ID = 4
```

How can I ensure that it copies the individual rows line by line?

I am not able to execute this query for some reason on sqlfiddle but I have tested it on my actual mysql database and the results are the same.

Comment: Your need is illogical. If you want to update Raspberry_data taking some data from Operation1 then you MUST build criteria expresstion which will set only one (or none) row from Operation1 which matches each separate row from Raspberry_data. But you do not use any matching criterion in your query at all - so the rows are updated using some indefinite source row. PS. Use [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=293c9f7101fa605678e78fdef40e58db) instead of provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What you said about the condition makes sense.. However, I am still unsure how can I achieve that. It is not important for me which one of two rows are set to ID = 4 and which one is ID = 6, as long as they are different and they are taken from Operation1 is all I need.

Comment: *as long as they are different* They differs in `ID` column value only, no other difference. And hence there is no any other way to distinguish them. Do not try to tell about their relative posession - it is fake and cannot be used.

Comment: Okay I see. So what if I do it one row at a time and change the ID. In my ID condition I would use something like : ```WHERE ID == 0``` so it does not modify the ID that has been already changed?

Comment: *So what if I do it one row at a time and change the ID.* This will solve the problem from one side - you do not need to distinguish rows in Operation1. But the problem from another side exists - you must specify what row must be updated, without this condition/restriction all rows in a table will be updated using the values from this alone source row.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I will look for a different approach to solve this then.